# Using asyncPipe to render data

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

I have function `renderImagePreview()` that provide for me string representation of file. And this function is async, clearly.

```
private renderImagePreview(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const fileReaderObs = new Observable((observer: any) => {
      reader.onload = () => {
        observer.next({ imagePath: reader.result as string });
        observer.complete();
      };
    });
    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    return fileReaderObs;
  }
```

I used `renderImagePreview()` inside subscription of parent function:

```
public onImagePicked(event: Event): void {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    if (file) {
      this.compressor.compress(file)
        .pipe(
          catchError(error => {
            return of(new Error(error));
          }),
          flatMap(image => {
            return of({
              renderFunction: this.renderImagePreview(image),
              image
            });
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            this.imagePreview = response.renderFunction;
            this.updateImageInForm(response.image);
          },
          (error) => { throw new Error(error); }
        );
    }
  }
```

As expected in my HTML i used this expression to render data:

```
<div class="image-preview" *ngIf="imagePreview">
    <img [src]="imagePreview | async">
</div>
```

There is something that i did in wrong way, but i don`t know what. Any ideas ?

**Try 1**

change: `observer.next(reader.result as string);`

change html:

`<div class="image-preview">
     <img [src]="imagePreview | async" [alt]="form.value.title">
 </div>`

result HTML: `<img _ngcontent-wja-c5="" src="null" alt="null">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public onImagePicked(event: Event): void {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    if (file) {
      this.compressor.compress(file)
        .pipe(
          catchError(error => {
            return of(new Error(error));
          }),
          flatMap(image => {
            return this.renderImagePreview(image).pipe(
              map((rendererResult) => {
                return {
                  'imagePath': rendererResult.imagePath,
                  'image': image
                };
              }
            )});
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            this.imagePreview = response.imagePath;
            this.updateImageInForm(response.image);
          },
          (error) => { throw new Error(error); }
        );
    }
  }
```

```
<div class="image-preview" *ngIf="imagePreview">
    <img [src]="imagePreview">
</div>
```

Comment: Also i added detectChanges() with ChangeDetectorRef after this.updateImageInForm(response.image);

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use as you are emiting `{ imagePath: reader.result as string }` :

```
[src]="(imagePreview | async)?.imagePath"
```

**OR**

Change

```
observer.next({ imagePath: reader.result as string });
```

To :

```
observer.next(reader.result as string);
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion. I edit my que so you can look at result.

Comment: @BrokenCoin,please create a demo over stackblitz with same issue if possible, then I might can help you, as there is lots of code and I dont know what data is coming or evenr any data is coming back or not.

Comment: Make sure you'r getting to code line - `this.imagePreview = response.renderFunction;`. add `console.log` before it to make sure.